# by Selecting datagridview combo box item, generates the txtboxcolumn value..how? in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

[image]

Hi, I want to perform the following operation on the grid view as the picture depicts.
By selecting the items from Item combo box, Unitprice will be generated in the Unit price txt field. The data of the item combo box binded by Product table. the value member of the Item combo box is Unitprice of the Product field. PLZ help me out. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Image link is broken, fyi.

Comment: Just make an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox` and update the corresponding cell's value in it.

Comment: @alldayremix please provide some details.can't showing the SelectedIndexChanged event in the datagrid view event list...thank u..

Comment: It would show up in the ComboBox event list, not the DataGridView event list. Can you [post some code](http://sscce.org/) showing your controls?

Comment: Actually the combo box is used as datagridview combo box column...so how to find the combo box event??

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the `CellValueChanged` event of the `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

    ' Update the unit price column whenever the value of the item cell changes.
    If DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) == DataGridView1.Item("Item", e.RowIndex) Then
        DataGridView1.Item("Unit Price", e.RowIndex).Value = DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value
End Sub
```

See also the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` [event reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) and the 'Remarks' section of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` [class reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx).

Comment: hv done it..with the hlp of this link...http://vbcity.com/forums/t/165337.aspx     thnxxx